# Strapi deployment config for lightsail

Tags: strapi, amazon-lightsail

Hi guys I'm facing some config issue when trying to deploy my strapi app through lightsail. I'm using strapi 4.16.2 hosted on lightsail.
I created a machine which gives me an IPv4 and an IPv6 IP address. I've tried setting this IPv6 Address in the config/env/production/server.js file. It looks something like this:

```
  proxy: true,
  url: env('URL'),
  port: env('PORT', '1337'), // This custom port will be important to point a domain to the service
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS')
  },
})
```

My `.env` File looks something like this:

```
JWT_SECRET=secret
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=secret
API_TOKEN_SALT=secret
APP_KEYS=secret
HOST=<my lightsail IPv4 Address>
PORT=1337
DATABASE_HOST=<My lightsail DB host url>
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_DB=rhp
DATABASE_USERNAME=<DB USER>
DATABASE_PW=<DB PW>
```

So in theory I should be able to see my app when visiting my lightsail IP Address:1337, correct? Unfortunately I don't get my strapi app but a timeout.

Can anyone help me with getting this running? Is there some other variable that I need to configure?
Any help would be appreciated,

Greetz